# Reading multiple data types from a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv

So I want to create a constructor that reads in a line of a file from a csv and save the first token into a variable and the remaining tokens into an array. This constructor will be used in a gradebook application but being new to txt/file manipulation I'm having a hard time.

A line will look like:

Billy Bob,68,79,95,83

I want to separate the tokens into these:

name = Billy Bob

grades[] = "68,79,95,83"

here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;


public class gradeBook {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Java Grade Book version 1.0");

        int lineCounter = 0;
        String array[];

        try{
            File data = new   File("/file/path/that/works");
            InputStream f = new FileInputStream(data);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(f));

            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line =     br.readLine()) {
                System.out.println(line); // just here to check that the code is working thus far

                //insert code here
                //name should equal first token (which is two names like Billy Bob)
                //grades[] should contain the other double type tokens (e.g. 56,87,89,90)
            }

            br.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: File Couldn't Be Read");
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to loop through the file to get as many students as are on the file stored so I can manipulate the grades for averages among other things. This is a personal project to help improve my developing skills so any help, useful tutorial links, and tips will be greatly appreciated. But please don't suggest simplistic examples like the many tutorials I have already read that only use one data type.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you implemented reading the file yet?

Comment: buffer reader and some other random things I don't really understand that I found in tutorials that didn't help. I can not find a definitive way to tokenize a line and store the tokens into variables, arrays, etc.

Comment: I know this Question is for practice, but FYI in real work I would use the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library to process such files.

Comment: Good to know thanks, is there a tutorial page or book you could recommend for learning more about Apache Commons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the line into an array;

```
String[] input = line.split(",");

String variable = input[0];

int[] grades= new int[input.lenght - 2];

for(int i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
{
    grades[i] = input[i];// you might have to do Integer.pareseInt(input[i]);
}
```

I did not write this in an IDE, but the logic should be correct.
You are going to run into a new problem. You grade book will only contain the last entry. Try using a 2D array for grades and 1D array for names; I personally would not use arrays. I would use arraylist.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot. Why use array list over array for this program?

Comment: I would only use arrays if I know the number of items that will be read from the file and this number never changes. Arraylist grows as needed.

Comment: Good point, I'll be sure to implement array lists when this program grows.

Answer (score 1):

So I haven't tested computing my tokens with methods or anything else yet but I have tokenized the line to sum (ha ha oops, meant some) degree with this bit of code:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            String name = tokens[0];
            String grade1 = tokens[1];
            String grade2 = tokens[2];
            String grade3 = tokens[3];
            String grade4 = tokens[4];
```